# Laravel - Emails with mailgun (on behalf of into) problem

Tags: php, laravel, api, mailgun

I'm using mailgun to send emails via Laravel API.
The emails are ok, I can send emails. But I noticed that when I receive an email it arrives with some strange message:

```
info=reporter.com@email.reporter.com on behalf of info@reporter.com
```

First I thought that my .env mail configuration was wrong, but know I notice its well configured:

```
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=info@reporter.com
```

Anyone has an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: just an observation. Noticed that I received emails from gitlab with that message to